# How to use BitmapDecoder with a non-seekable stream?

Tags: wpf

I have a non-seekable stream holding a PNG file. I'd like to decode this using WPF's `BitmapDecoder` class. The documentation doesn't state that I must pass a seekable stream, nor does the code throw if I do so, so I conclude it's supposed to work.

However, I can't get it to work. Here's a contrived example showing the problem:

```
// This is an 8x8 all-red PNG:
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAIAAABLb"
            + "SncAAAAEElEQVQIHWP8z4AdMA4tCQB8/QgBp6L0HwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");

BitmapDecoder decoder;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                                   BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

Console.WriteLine(decoder.Frames[0].PixelWidth); // outputs 8, correctly

using (var stream = new UnseekableStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
    decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                                   BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

Console.WriteLine(decoder.Frames[0].PixelWidth); // outputs 1, wrongly
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615982.aspx) states that I should be able to dispose of the stream immediately if I pass in the `OnLoad` flag, which I do.

Of course I could just read the whole thing into a `MemoryStream` first, but that doesn't sound right. Am I doing something wrong, or is `BitmapDecoder` being buggy here?

P.S. Here's the "compressed" source for `UnseekableStream` used in the example above:

```
public sealed class UnseekableStream : Stream
{
    private Stream _stream;
    public UnseekableStream(Stream underlyingStream) { _stream = underlyingStream; }

    private bool _disposed = false;
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        _disposed = true; _stream.Dispose(); base.Dispose();
    }
    public override bool CanSeek { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return _stream.CanWrite; } }
    public override bool CanRead { get { return _stream.CanRead; } }
    public override void Flush() { _stream.Flush(); }
    public override long Length { get { return _stream.Length; } }
    public override void SetLength(long value) { _stream.SetLength(value); }
    public override long Position { get { return _stream.Position; } set { _stream.Position = value; } }
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { return _stream.Seek(offset, origin); }
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { return _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count); }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `PngBitmapDecoder` directly:

```
using (var stream = new UnseekStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
{
    decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```

I guess the stream only needs to be seekable for `BitmapDecoder.Create` to find out which image format it contains before actually decoding it by a suitable decoder.

Comment: @romkyns Exactly. To find out what image format it is, you first have to inspect the stream, then rewind and actually decode. Therefore `BitmapDecoder.Create` needs to seek.

Comment: If it needs seek, it should a) throw if it can't have it, and b) document this fact. The code for `PngBitmapDecoder` suggests that it also needs seek; it just happens to correctly wrap the non-seekable stream when need be...

Comment: I fully agree, it should never silently fail and return garbage. Or does it simply rely on the stream to throw a `NotSupportedException` when `Seek` is called, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: No, just changed your code to throw a `NotSupportedException` in `Seek`. It's not called at all.